# "Three" most popular

Tags: phrase-usage, grammatical-number, numbers

**Most** - greatest in amount, quantity, or degree.

> Three most popular brands ... ...
> Three most popular classes ... ...

We often search for **N* most popular* but is it standard English to add counts before *most*? In the example sentences, *Three most popular* mean they are equally popular and none of them is better than another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is acceptable and quite common to add a count like this. But it doesn't mean that they are equal.  So if you write "The three most popular drinks are tea, coffee and water." It doesn't mean that they are equally popular, but it doesn't necessarily tell you which is first, second or third. Though it is natural to order the list if that is possible.

> The three richest men in the world — Bill Gates, Carlos Slim and Warren Buffett — now have a combined $244 billion. ([NBC](https://www.facebook.com/NBCNews/posts/the-three-richest-men-in-the-world-bill-gates-carlos-slim-and-warren-buffett-now/1004751746211522/))

The word "Top" is often added, especially in the form "The top ten ..."

> The top ten most popular registered dog breeds in the UK: ([source](https://www.pets4homes.co.uk/pet-advice/the-top-ten-most-popular-registered-dog-breeds-in-the-uk.html))
>
> 1. Labrador
> 2. ...